# Does Autofac instance registered SingleInstance() survive IIS AppDomain recycling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have been using `Autofac` integration with `ASP.NET Web API` and `ASP.NET MVC`. Everything seems to be working fine, except that I have some lingering doubt over the lifecycle of objects that are registered as `SingleInstance()`, and more broadly about the lifetime of the container itself.

For example, if I declare a class as follows:

```
public class Cache {
    private Dictionary<int, int> _internalCache = new Dictionary<int, int>();        
}
```

and registers it as single-instance in the container:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<Cache>.SingleInstance();
var container = builder.Build();
```

Assuming that I use the same `container` instance for both `ASP.NET MVC` and `ASP.NET Web API` integration, hosted in `IIS`, what happens to the container and instances that is registered under it when the `AppDomain` recycles? What happens to the content of `_internalCache`? If I resolve `Cache` before and after the `AppDomain` recycles, will I still get the same instance?

Comment: Short answer **no**.... [nice explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31700662/1062224)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recycling a *IIS Application pool* will restart the *w3wp.exe*. After recycling everything will be reset and you will have a new instance of `Cache` : **one instance of `Cache` for each application pool instance**.

By the way, when you recycle your application pool, IIS will :

1. start a new application pool : a new w3wp.exe will start
2. wait for the new application pool to be up : ASP.net will initialize itself, this is when your *Autofac* container should be built
3. gracefully shutdown the first application pool. All running request will complete on the old application pool and new request will be redirected to the new application pool. (The old application pool will be shut down when all old requests complete or after timeout)

When the new application pool is starting, the other is still live, so it is possible to have 2 concurrent instances of `Cache` living at the same moment but in 2 distinct application pool.

Comment: Does it also apply for things like Azure website or web role? I imagine there is IIS behind the scene, so same thing applies